# How to include .so file of another project into our own project?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I have a .so file of some project but now i want to include that file in my project. i tried all the possibilities. i used below samples

```
task copyJniLibs(type: Copy) {
    from 'libs/armeabi'
    into 'src/main/jniLibs/armeabi'
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(copyJniLibs)
}
clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyJniLibs'
```

and copied .so files in jnilibs folder as suggested in few answer but still getting same error as

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.manvish.gpio.MainActivity.setGpioDataHigh:(I)Z
```

Comment: You copy-paste it into the library folder or whereever native files go... It isn't rocket science

Comment: Yes i did..but still getting the same error @Zoe

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all these gradle tasks. It's enough to set

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

But then, the question is if the native library you've got in `libs/armeabi` implements the native method. If it does, it exports a  function with a specially crafted name `Java_com_example_manvish_gpio_MainActivity_setGpioDataHigh`.